# How to read XML header in Python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing

How can I read the header of an XML document in Python 3?

Ideally, I would use the defusedxml module as the [documentation states that it's safer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html), but at this point (after hours of trying to figure this out), I'd settle for any parser.

For example, I have a document (this is actually from an exercise) that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0"> <!-- this is root -->
    <!-- CONTENTS -->
</plist>
```

I'm wondering how to access everything before the root node.

This seems like such a general question that I thought I would easily find an answer online, but I guess I was wrong. The closest thing I found was [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155102/how-to-read-in-xml-header-version-using-python), which didn't really help (I looked into [xml.sax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.sax.html), but couldn't find anything relevant).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried [`minidom`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.dom.minidom.html) which is vulnerable to billion laughs and quadratic blowup attacks according to [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html) you provided. Here is my code:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

dom = parse('file.xml')
print('<?xml version="{}" encoding="{}"?>'.format(dom.version, dom.encoding))
print(dom.doctype.toxml())
#or
print(dom.getElementsByTagName('plist')[0].previousSibling.toxml())
#or
print(dom.childNodes[0].toxml())
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist  PUBLIC '-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN'  'http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd'>
<!DOCTYPE plist  PUBLIC '-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN'  'http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd'>
<!DOCTYPE plist  PUBLIC '-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN'  'http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd'>
```

You can use `minidom` from `defusedxml`. I downloaded that package and just replaced import with `from defusedxml.minidom import parse` and code worked with same output.

Comment: Brilliant! That's exactly what I was looking for. The third option (childNodes[0]) seems to be the most generic for getting all headers.

Comment: I'm glad I helped :-)

Answer (score 5):

With the [lxml](http://lxml.de) library, you can access document properties via a [`DocInfo`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.DocInfo-class.html) object.

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('input.xml')
info = tree.docinfo
v, e, d = info.xml_version, info.encoding, info.doctype

print('<?xml version="{}" encoding="{}"?>'.format(v, e))
print(d)
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly well, but I've accepted @mike-kaskun's answer because (a) of defusedxml and (b) minidom seems to be a default package (at least on my system) vs lxml which I had to install.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code !
I am assuming the temporary xml in variable 's' .

I am declare a class of MyParser having a function of XmlDecl to print the XML header & the purpose of second function is to parse the XML header .so first create the parser by using the ParserCreate() function defined in xml.parsers .

Now create the object of MyParser class 'parser' & call the parse function with the object reference.

```
from xml.parsers import expat

s = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='iso-8859-1'?>
       <book>
           <title>Title</title>
           <chapter>Chapter 1</chapter>
       </book>"""

class MyParser(object):
    def XmlDecl(self, version, encoding, standalone):
        print ("XmlDecl", version, encoding, standalone)

    def Parse(self, data):
        Parser = expat.ParserCreate()
        Parser.XmlDeclHandler = self.XmlDecl
        Parser.Parse(data, 1)

parser = MyParser()
parser.Parse(s)
```

Comment: Thanks, but see clarification in question. Also, I find it difficult to follow your code; maybe some comments or simplifications would help.

Comment: yes sure ! I am updating the description above in a while @Ratler

Comment: that doesn't really help actually. And it's still not getting the full headers before the root node.