# How to retrieve the doctype of the xml file

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

I need a python code which returns 5.6.0 which is the version of the xml.

I have already tried to retrieve the doctype but I failed.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC 
 "-//ES//DTD journal article DTD version 5.6.0//EN//XML" 
 "art560.dtd" [<!ENTITY gr1 SYSTEM "gr1" NDATA IMAGE>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it return 1.0. That's what is in your xml version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read XML header in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48941032/how-to-read-xml-header-in-python)

Comment: `etree.parse('input.xml').docinfo.public_id` will extract `"-//ES//DTD journal article DTD version 5.6.0//EN//XML"`; use a regex on that.

Comment: @Joe: nice solution but it produces this error:

AttributeError: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'docinfo'

Comment: As per the linked question; with `from lxml import etree`.

Comment: If you think I answered your question, you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
xmlstring = '''  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC 
 "-//ES//DTD journal article DTD version 5.6.0//EN//XML" 
 "art560.dtd" [<!ENTITY gr1 SYSTEM "gr1" NDATA IMAGE>'''
version = xmlstring.split("version")[2].split("//")[0]
print(version)
```

Stackoverflow syntax highlighting renders it weird but it runs-